# Forcing/rewriting method from POST to GET in Apache internally

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I get a POST request like `/grabcontent?url=/foo/bar.html` on my Apache server.

(yes, I know a POST request with a URL parameter makes no sense, but this is what I am getting from a 3rd party, cannot change this at the moment.)

`/foo/bar.html` is actually a valid page on my server.

How can I change this into a GET request to `/foo/bar.html`?

I know how to extract the URL parameter value, I know how to change the request internally using mod_rewrite.
But how can I change the request from POST to GET internally?

I could write a dummy script that simply fetches content and map it to `/grabcontent` of course, but I would rather avoid the extra overhead and use Apache out-of-the-box functionality.

Comment: You don't need to convert the method from POST to GET as sending either to a static resource  will simply result in that resource getting returned to the client. The static resource simply won't do any form of processing on the POST data and discard it...

Comment: Not in my case as it goes to a Java application server.

Comment: If you are going to be able to do this at all I would have thought you would need to do this at the point you send the request to the "Java application server"? How is this currently being achieved? Through a proxy? AFAIK you can't do this with mod_rewrite alone. Ordinarily you would do something like a 303 (or 302) _external_ redirect and let the user-agent/browser reissue a GET request. But obviously this is "external", not "internal" to your server. And if the "3rd party" doesn't follow redirects (or does it?) it will just fail.